# How can I ignore to follow symbolic links with grep?

Tags: unix

> How can I ignore to follow symbolic links with grep ?

I tried to use with grep -R but it don't help me

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep -r` instead.  It doesn't follow symbolic links .... according to the manual entry!

Another option would be to use `find <dir> -P -type f ... | xargs grep ...`.  (Or leave out the `-P` because not following symlinks is default behavior for `find`.  If you have whitespace in pathnames, use `find ... -path0` and `xargs -0`.)

Comment: grep -r does follow links

Comment: give me example please. @Stephen C

Comment: The manual entry on my machine says *"-r, --recursive
              Read  all  files  under  each  directory, recursively, **following
              symbolic links only if they are on the command line**.  Note  that
              if   no  file  operand  is  given,  grep  searches  the  working
              directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option."*   What does your manual entry say?

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: What doesn't work for you?  What does `man grep` say?  That OS and version are you using?  What does `grep --version` say?

Comment: If you're running on Mac, the shipped grep is BSD grep which doesn't ignore symlinks. You have to install GNU grep with `brew install grep`.

Brew doesn't replace system grep, you have to call it with 2 g's: `ggrep`